# Child Routing in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

i am trying to route to LocationComponent. Well i want to make Locationcomponent a child of Foodcomponent so the url would be like "localhost:4200/admin/food/location. How do i get this done? Thank you

```
export const PanelRoutes: Routes =[

  {
    path: 'admin',

    component: AdminPanelComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'game'},
      {path: 'game', component: GameComponent},
      {path: 'food', component: FoodComponent},
      {path: 'location', component: LocationComponent},

    ];


  }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [

        AppComponent,
        ...DashboardComponentList
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. You already have `FoodComponent` (and `GameComponent`, `LocationComponent`) a child of `AdminPanelComponent`. Why don't you do the same with `FoodComponent` and `LocationComponent`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, you mean i should create a full routes for food just like i have done with AdminPanelComponent?

Comment: Like cyrix shows in his answer. "doesn't work" is not very helpful. Please explain what the expected behavior and the actual behavior is and if you get an error message and what exactly the error is.

Comment: I am trying to make location a child of food component where foodcomponent is a child of the adminpanelcomponent. Now when cyrix answer which i already tried before posting question gives me an error saying " URL segment does not match admin"

Comment: I guess we need more information. Please add `@NgModel()` of your `AppModule` to your question.

Comment: In the DashboardComponentList, I have FoodComponent and LocationComponent in it

Comment: How do you provide the router and routes?

Comment: if i get you right, i have a routing page for my routes and in my admin page, i have the router-outlet there.   Anyway, i am translating from english to deutsch so pardon if any wrong communication

Comment: "if I get you right"? I was mostly asking, not making a statement or explanation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminPanelComponent,
  children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'game'},
    {path: 'game', component: GameComponent},
    {path: 'food', component: FoodComponent, children: [
      {path: 'location', component: LocationComponent}
    ]},
  ];
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `<router-outlet>` inside your FoodComponent? If not you need one.

Comment: So like Günter said please provide more information about the error your facing.